# Elapsed Time can't get hr:min with LibreOffice...?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

How can I get my Elapsed Time column to come out in and Hour and Minutes format? I have the time cells formatted to Time & 13:37 and I've tried every available choice but no matter what for 24 hour times such as start 18:06 stop 19:22 I get and Elapsed time of 0.0527777778. I want 1hr: 16min, I can get it in MS Office on another computer but not with my laptop running LibreOffice. What gives here and yes I'm a dunce with Excel

Answer (score 1):

How can I get my Elapsed Time column to come out in and Hour and Minutes format?

1. Right click the "Elapsed Time" cell (`C2`) in my example
2. Select "Format cells..."
3. Select "Numbers" tab
4. Set the "Category" to "Time"
5. Set the "Format code" to "HH:MM"
6. Press "OK"

   [image]

Comment: Thanks I have tried that but I can't high light/click any block in the elapsed time column at all. Blocks on both sides yes but the elapsed time column  I cannot edit or format at all. It's stuck or locked in whatever that format it is displaying..! still trying

Comment: Check the "Cell Protection" tab (same dialog) to make sure you haven't protected the cells.

Comment: i cannot highlight any cell in the column only adjacent cells so I can not get to a cell protection of format menu for those cells in the elapsed time column

Comment: @Ronan That's weird. Can you select the whole column by clicking on the column header letter?

Comment: no clicking the column header letter does nothing nor the column title

Comment: @Ronan Last thing to try. Select the whole spreadsheet (ctrl+a?) and see if you can format cells and unprotect everything.